# How to forecast low values in data more accurately than the higher values?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I have a scenario where I have to forecast small values in data more accurately than the higher values. I have data set as below

```
start_time          count

2019-12-14 10:00:00 20
2019-12-14 11:00:00 15      
2019-12-14 12:00:00 3      
2019-12-14 13:00:00 5       
2019-12-14 14:00:00 10
2019-12-14 15:00:00 13      
2019-12-14 16:00:00 7  
2019-12-14 17:00:00 17  
2019-12-14 18:00:00 5 
2019-12-14 19:00:00 4 
2019-12-14 20:00:00 10 
2019-12-14 21:00:00 10
2019-12-14 22:00:00 10
2019-12-14 23:00:00 4
```

I have to forecast low values like 3,4,5 etc... more closely/accurately than other higher values like 10,14,17 etc...

I have tried ARIMA model with all different variations of P,D,Q values. However, I don't get the best match. Over all forecasting performs good but the models fail in predicting lower values or sudden drop in value.

What model should I use to solve my problem?

Thank you